# contenteditable double click selection bug or feature?

Tags: html, contenteditable

here: https://jsfiddle.net/xuw0m552/1/

```
  <div contenteditable="true" style="background-color: #dadada">asdasda asdasdas</div>
```

*background is set so you you can see the block's boundaries and you know where to click*

If I double click inside the DIV on the right from entered text it selects the last word (correct behavior)

and here: https://jsfiddle.net/5gupsLb1/1/

```
  <div contenteditable="true" style="background-color: #dadada">asdasda asdasdas</div>
  <div>111111</div>
```

if that DIV has anything but closed `</body>` tag after it - double click does nothing.

Question: how do I fix that? and why is this happening?